# Opening an existing siaqodb instance on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone

I manage to create a database and use it, but get an exception when trying to initiate from an existing one.

```
var store = new Siaqodb("storageplace");
```

> Additional information: GenericArguments[0], 'System.Nullable`1[System.Double]', on '#=qestOt0Z3wa12dRPJi9vYcGXf14qUdof1q8lAg3hgeMk=[#=qCmB_qbvBwSH22$$JQWSgOA==]' violates the constraint of type '#=qCmB_qbvBwSH22$$JQWSgOA=='.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You probably added an index on a Nullable types. Indexes on nullable types are not supported.